# What statistical functions come native to C# and T-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm a fledgling DBA dealing with some medical data.  While I've not yet gotten to the point of needing top-tier statistical methods, I will soon.  I plan to put several databases online and searchable for whatever the user wants.  My question is, besides average, standard deviation, etc. does T SQL have any other statistical functions?  And for C#?  Are free libraries for things such as this readily available, or would I have to make it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about T-SQL, but in C# there is [dnAnalytics](http://dnanalytics.codeplex.com/) which offers various functions concerning descriptive statistics. I've used it on various occasions and was very satisfied with the results achieved, performance and overall library design.

Comment: Note that dnAnalytics is (for the most part) dead. It was merged into Math.Net http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/

Comment: i read somewhere else about math.net, i will certainly check it out.